# fetch duplicate result as one set with all the unique values in duplicate rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

my table (tbl) has duplicate rows for same bookid my need is to fetch it as one set with all the unique values

```
table1

id  bookId  format
1   123      A
2   123      B
3   123      C
4   123      D
```

My need is to get result set as following

```
     bookID      format
      123        A,B,C,D
```

A join would be much tedious. is there something i dont know ?do i loop it?

Comment: And you want to do that using SQL or PHP? It's not clear as you tagged `PHP` for this question.

Comment: Maybe the php tag should be removed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) :

```
SELECT t.bookID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t.format ORDER BY t.format) as `format`
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.bookID
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

```
SELECT bookID,GROUP_CONCAT(format) FROM table1 GROUP BY bookID
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cdef6/1)**

Comment: This doesn't force his desired order, and he asked for all the "unique values" , it doesn't seem like there are any duplicates formats, but he did ask for it for a reason I guess.